# Application Error when deploying Strapi to Heroku, but succcessful build?

Tags: node.js, heroku, strapi

I'm really new to Strapi followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_MwTnHpUGg&ab_channel=ProgrammingNight) to deploy it using MongoDB and Heroku. The Strapi app successfully deployed to Heroku, but when I opened it, it says

"Application Error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

Here's the build log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       USE_YARN_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.15.5...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.11
       Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.10)
       Installed yarn 1.22.10
        !     node_modules checked into source control
              https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.22.10
       warning package.json: No license field
       warning No license field
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary@3.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "strapi-plugin-upload@^3.1.6".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 6.43s.
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       yarn install v1.22.10
       warning package.json: No license field
       warning No license field
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary@3.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "strapi-plugin-upload@^3.1.6".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
       Done in 0.72s.
       
-----> Caching build
       - yarn cache
       
-----> Build succeeded!
 !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
 !     Unmet dependencies don't fail yarn install but may cause runtime issues
       https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 34.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v10
       https://we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Here's the output of `heroku logs`:

```
2021-02-21T06:22:05.341700+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T06:22:50.951762+00:00 app[api]: Rollback to v10 by user merinetan@gmail.com
2021-02-21T06:22:50.951762+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user merinetan@gmail.com
2021-02-21T06:22:52.245919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T06:22:54.607923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T06:22:56.386071+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T06:22:56.394175+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T06:22:56.394498+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T06:22:56.394653+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T06_22_56_386Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T06:22:56.442808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T06:22:56.495544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T06:25:45.223881+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=3ed63d3e-e250-4626-b783-02203af73712 fwd="3.80.167.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:26:05.476448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=78bb4932-55ce-49aa-b9ad-11ff1e09a70f fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:28:23.814694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=9a3d44c0-03f4-4b27-9f43-f61c232ad732 fwd="107.23.45.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:28:24.092182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=8a12e8ff-6d68-4265-96f7-69a8696c25a7 fwd="107.23.45.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:30:18.240690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=a2033709-b957-4be0-ab71-c6b987bbf3ab fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:30:24.317897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=f4ab55e4-9e7c-4a29-8117-9cbdb53fc20e fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:35:39.745213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T06:35:42.237997+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T06:35:44.215838+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T06:35:44.221068+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T06:35:44.221326+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T06:35:44.221405+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T06_35_44_216Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T06:35:44.270848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T06:35:44.328081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T06:36:24.094434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=3c048bbc-721a-4b96-bd5c-15eaab20b7d1 fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:36:25.661453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=870ef876-31f7-4e52-9b25-c9ec0c4d6cb8 fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:36:29.413655+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=249b6bdb-6d8d-4890-b6e0-ad6aa7555578 fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:36:29.981010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=8fd73cd3-b900-42a0-b28c-d5a940c2ef06 fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:48:56.447385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=d581c5b1-da4a-455b-8b3b-527494420dad fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T06:48:58.252921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=8e7c0f9a-d11e-4542-aff0-c466f61300ce fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T07:00:03.313920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T07:00:06.449360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T07:00:09.380555+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T07:00:09.385558+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T07:00:09.385832+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T07:00:09.385944+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T07_00_09_381Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T07:00:09.471304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T07:00:09.542349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T07:50:27.036632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=07fdd52d-a5da-41ba-aa04-f9709c15c1cd fwd="193.27.12.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T07:55:10.471814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T07:55:13.315292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T07:55:15.630158+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T07:55:15.639782+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T07:55:15.640206+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T07:55:15.640407+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T07_55_15_631Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T07:55:15.691414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T07:55:15.759805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T07:56:03.843654+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T09:38:30.628336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T09:38:33.486003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T09:38:37.077175+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T09:38:37.083975+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T09:38:37.084256+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T09:38:37.084355+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T09_38_37_077Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T09:38:37.151682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T09:38:37.210620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T10:02:04.794170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=8d7e9a50-825d-4ace-9433-2a0e1aecd135 fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T12:23:54.511630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T12:23:58.090780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T12:24:01.254908+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T12:24:01.263262+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T12:24:01.263926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T12:24:01.264231+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T12_24_01_255Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T12:24:01.315068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T12:24:01.404682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T12:53:08.465603+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=5b79c5f7-0c59-4e42-ad30-95828185385b fwd="182.253.245.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T12:53:10.017483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=we-the-genesis-strapi.herokuapp.com request_id=e0d2774b-915a-41e1-b54b-1b13f8af4991 fwd="182.253.245.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-21T17:49:02.615126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T17:49:05.568155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T17:49:08.048349+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T17:49:08.055280+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T17:49:08.055495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T17:49:08.055581+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T17_49_08_049Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T17:49:08.101618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T17:49:08.181685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-21T23:41:17.655463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-21T23:41:20.342548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-21T23:41:22.677531+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-21T23:41:22.685929+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-21T23:41:22.686316+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-21T23:41:22.686514+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-21T23_41_22_678Z-debug.log
2021-02-21T23:41:22.747850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-21T23:41:22.811171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-22T05:33:36.567171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-22T05:33:38.989078+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-22T05:33:41.308054+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-22T05:33:41.315909+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-22T05:33:41.316276+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-22T05:33:41.316446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-22T05_33_41_308Z-debug.log
2021-02-22T05:33:41.360219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-22T05:33:41.409789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-22T11:25:55.927138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-22T11:25:58.546244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-02-22T11:26:00.817024+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-02-22T11:26:00.825946+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-22T11:26:00.826186+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-22T11:26:00.826277+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-22T11_26_00_817Z-debug.log
2021-02-22T11:26:00.864484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-22T11:26:00.927770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the output of `heroku logs` to the question?

Comment: Added it, there seems to be an error. Thanks

Comment: You've to pass the app id to the command — `heroku logs -a we-the-genesis-strapi`